# Understanding FreebSD tax file naming conventions

Tags: freebsd

I was trying FreeBSD and looked in the packages folder on the DVD for python packages. The saw the following:

```
python-2.7_2,2.txz
python2-2_3.txz
python27-2.7.12.txz
```

Am I to understand there are three separate packages here, called `python`, `python2` and `python27`? If so, how do I read the version numbers? What significance do the `_` an `,` in the filenames have? Do I have to install a specific one or am I free to choose based on the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three packages just happen to be identical at this moment in time.

`python27` installs the latest stable version of Python 2.7.x

`python2` installs the latest stable version of Python 2.x.x, which will be Python 2.7.x until Python 2.8 is considered stable enough to replace it.**<sup>‡</sup>**

`python` installs the latest stable version of Python, which happens to be the same as the above, presumably until Python 3 is considered stable enough to replace it.

So you need to decide which version numbers are important to you, and which you are happy to track.

But as I said at the start, looking at the [FreeBSD website](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=python&stype=all&sektion=lang), all three currently install Python 2.7.12.

Generally, anything before the hyphen is part of the FreeBSD package name, and anything between the `-` and `,` is the actual version of the item. Any number after a ',' represents a bump in the (FreeBSD) package version where the item's version has not changed.

<sup>‡</sup> Although as Roland Smith commented, this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: There will be no Python 2.8. At some point, FreeBSD will have to switch to Python 3 as the default Python. This is being worked on.